# Building C# code in VSCode on Mac

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin, command-line-interface, visual-studio-code

I've been building a command line tool using Xamarin. After being told about Visual Studio Code, I wanted to see if I could try using it as an editor and debugger.

I managed to get it to debug an **existing** `.exe` file built with Xamarin, by editing the `launch.json` file, and it knows which source files to jump into when stepping through the code.

However, I can't work out how to actually get it to compile a new executable? Whenever I make any changes to the source, it simply debugs the old executable that's in `<my project>/<my project>/bin/Debug/<project>.exe`, as was the default in Xamarin.

It seems to understand the source code itself since it has a load of warnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can setup a build task to compile the modified source. See https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/tasks or http://blog.denouter.net/2015/04/compile-visual-studio-solution-in.html

Comment: Does this mean that you have to manually use a build task to build the code, then as a separate command, choose to debug it? i.e. no way to use a single command to build + debug as you would do in most IDEs?

Comment: @JosephHumfrey you can specify a dependency task to run before any other gulp task using the second parameter. So the following will run build then debug: `gulp.task('debug', ['build'], function(done) { ... });`

Answer (score -1):

You use mcs, for example:

mcs -out:program.exe -recurse:'*.cs'